# Reserved keywords count by programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, keyword

Is there a ranking or table of the number of reserved keywords in various programming languages?

I do not need to know the keywords per se but how many keywords languages like C, C++, C#, Perl, Python, PHP, Smalltalk, Lisp, and Ruby have.

Comment: I guess a bit of googling syntax specs could reveal this easily.

Comment: [iota](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota) : 2

Comment: https://github.com/e3b0c442/keywords

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Lists of keywords in ...

- [ANSI COBOL 85](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zh/SSZJPZ_9.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.mfjob.dev.doc/topics/r_dmnjbref_COBOL_Reserved_Words.html): 357
- [SystemVerilog](https://www.globalspec.com/reference/79171/203279/appendix-b-verilog-and-systemverilog-reserved-keywords): 250 + 73 reserved system functions = 323
- [VHDL 2008](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/ite_r_vhdl_reserved_words.htm): 115 reserved words
- [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx): 79 + 23 contextual = 102
- [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx): 64 + 8 from ocaml + 26 future = 98
- [C++](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/start): 82
- [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour): 54
- [Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html): 50 (48 without unused keywords `const` and `goto`)
- [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php): 49
- [Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) 42
- [JavaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words): 38 reserved words + 8 words reserved in strict mode only
- [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords): 35
- [C](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html): 32
- [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords): 31
- [Go](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords): 25
- [Elm](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/d07679322ef5d71de1bd2b987ddc660a85599b87/compiler/src/Parse/Primitives/Keyword.hs#L3-L12) : 25
- [Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1): 22
- [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#annotated-source): 19, not
  necessarily "reserved", plus ~50 to avoid from JS
- [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Syntax): 6 pseudo-variables
- [iota](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota): 2

Comment: Thanks aioobe. You said searching for "<language> keyword" is enough but most of the results list functions instead of reporting the amount, so you have to count manually each function? Take the first hit of Perl for example: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html

Comment: yeah. I punch in `wc -l <enter>` in my terminal, and paste in the lists.

Comment: Damn I was hoping to find SQL

Comment: @JMG me too. Took a count in this page https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm and came to a staggering 480. Anyone higher? ;-)

Comment: btw, would be nice if someone compiled all these keywords in the single table/list (which could be filtered based by languages selected).

Comment: IMHO, the count for C is misleading - `NULL`, `size_t` though not listed as keywords are widely used [macros](  http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/stddef.html), including K&R's [second}(https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628) edition. On a related note, Python 3's count of 33 includes `None`, `True` and `False` as keywords.

Comment: The page linked in the answer (ecma-international.org) seems more authoritative than w3schools tbh. I'm no JavaScript expert, but why does w3schools list `synchronized`? I doubt that's correct, since JavaScript doesn't have multithreading. Same with `volatile`. Also, what's up with `double`, `float`, `byte` etc?

Comment: Several links are not working anymore, the first one even leads to a phishing site

Comment: @maja thanks, went through the list and updated broken links.

Comment: What about ABAP programming language? It seems like there is 901 (key)-words for NW 7.50 release. It depends on whether you treat those words as keywords, but since ABAP is based mainly on COBOL (present in the list above), it would make sense to add it to the list either. Take a look here: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_words.htm

Comment: How about Rust?